# How to retrieve a React component from an object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I've got a `SliderMenu` React component, which receives an array containing its elements. These elements are objects, and one of their properties is the icon that will be shown in the menu:

```
function SliderMenu({ options }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Drawer open>
        <List>
          {options.map((item) => {
            const { icon: ItemIcon } = item || {};
            return (
              <ListItem button key={`menuItem_${item.text.replace(/\s/g, '')}`}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <ItemIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={item.text} />
              </ListItem>
            );
          })}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
    </>
  );
}
```

This component is called from an upper component (because I'd like to be able to create multiple `SliderMenu` if I needed them), which specifies the elements array and passes them as props:

```
import React from 'react';
import { HomeRoundedIcon } from '@material-ui/icons/HomeRounded';
import SliderMenu from '../../components/SliderMenu';

function MainMenu() {
  const menuOptions = [
    {
      text: 'Home',
      icon: HomeRoundedIcon,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <SliderMenu options={menuOptions} />
  );
}

export default MainMenu;
```

The problem here is that whenever I try this code, `ItemIcon` is undefined, and I'm receiving the following error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `SliderMenu`.

However, if I try:

```
const menuOptions = [
    {
        text: 'Home',
        icon: <HomeRoundedIcon />,
    },
];
```

`ItemIcon` has a value, and I get the following error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `SliderMenu`.

I would like to be able to specify different menu elements with different icons and so on, depending on the context, and then use the common component to render it and have a consistent behaviour across all menus.

**How can I define the icon in the object, using the icon component library, and then pass it via `props` to the `SliderMenu` so it can render it** (without having to import all the icons and make a switch to see which icon has to render)?

Comment: i wonder if you should be exporting the default instead i.e. `import  HomeRoundedIcon  from '@material-ui/icons/HomeRounded';` based on their docs https://material-ui.com/components/icons/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your import to a default import

```js
import HomeRoundedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/HomeRounded'
```

or use a named import from `@material-ui/icons` path

```js
import { HomeRounded as HomeRoundedIcon } from "@material-ui/icons"
```

You would also want to remove the default assignment and render the icon conditionally as this will throw an error when there is no icon

```js
const { icon: ItemIcon } = item

{ItemIcon && (
  <ListItemIcon>
    <ItemIcon />
  </ListItemIcon>
)}
```

Comment: Yes! The conditional I was going to put that check, but I came across the error and I got stuck in that. I will try your solution asap to see if it works! Thank you!

Comment: Finally, it seems it was because of the import issue, as you commented. Thank you for your help!